# What should i test in styled component?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am making an app with styled-components and JEST for testing. I am super new in testing and here is my question, What should I test in styled-components cuz in my opinion there is no reason to test a styled component

Comment: You can do snapshot testing to see if the DOM element correctly renders with props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to test packages utils like verify that their function return correctly this or that..., they are made from professionnals teams, that are constently maintaining their packages.

What you could test, especially if you're new to testing to explore a bit the differents usages is :

Create a mock with few props that you setup before mounting your component (im talking in jest)

Find a particular element with his attribute, or classname and test that this element values is what you've setup in the mock, test that element is correctly rendered, and if you really want to see if your styled components class or properties are there, you could aswell check some class your element has, or particular style.

I couldn't advice you more to read more about testing and practice it, you will learn a lot of things starting by a project simple like that where you could jsut test your public API.

There you find some documentation about what i was mentionning above:

Expects functions : https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect (Start with easy one first, like toBe(),toEqual() for objects, toContain, ect...

Global API: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api

And more advanced :
Mocks setup : https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api
Async code: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async